# Principled BSDF ,micro displacement turns black with normal map

Tags: normal-map, opencl

not sure if its supported or not, i'm using an AMD RX Vega56 (OpenCL).
using a normal map in the principled BSDF + micro displacement gets me just a blck hole.

is it supported?

thanks for the help :)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: actual render]
[image: actual render-microdisplacement]

[Normal map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q05bZJRffc1Hq64NAHB09hzigpgGLqnH)

Comment: how does an actual render look like? Also can you attach the normal map image texture?

Comment: i added actual render and a link to the normal map. the map was bakes in blender cycles.

Comment: did you unwrap your model?

Comment: yes. everything works perfectly fine without adaptive turned on.

Comment: after some more digging it appears to be a known bug. thank for the help :)